# In Swift, how can I specify a typealias that restricts RawRepresentable to String?

Tags: swift, rawrepresentable

I'm trying to define a protocol that requires an `enum` with raw value `String` to be implemented.

I don't believe that it's currently possible to enforce the use of `enum`, and I'm not sure I *really* care as long as somewhere down the line I can call `fromRaw()` and receive a `String`.

So, I'm trying to maintain the brevity of the following while restricting `Beta` to be an `enum` where the raw value is a `String`:

```
protocol Alpha {
    typealias Beta: RawRepresentable
}

struct Gamma: Alpha {
    enum Beta: String {
        case Delta = "delta"
    }
}

struct Eta<T: Alpha, U: RawRepresentable where T.Beta == U> {
    let alpha: T
    let beta: U
    init(alpha: T, beta: U) {
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.beta = beta
        println("beta is: \(beta.toRaw())")
    }
}

let gamma = Gamma()
Eta(alpha: gamma, beta: .Delta) // "beta is delta"
```

The problem with the above is that other raw values are allowed, and therefore this is valid:

```
struct Epsilon: Alpha {
    enum Beta: Int {
        case Zeta = 6
    }
}

let epsilon = Epsilon()
Eta(alpha: epsilon, beta: .Zeta) // "beta is 6"
```

To address that I'm currently doing this:

```
protocol StringRawRepresentable: RawRepresentable {
    class func fromRaw(raw: String) -> Self?
}

protocol Alpha {
    typealias Beta: StringRawRepresentable
}

struct Gamma: Alpha {
    enum Beta: String, StringRawRepresentable {
        case Delta = "delta"
    }
}

// Type 'Epsilon' does not conform to protocol 'Alpha'
struct Epsilon: Alpha {
    enum Beta: Int {
        case Zeta = 6
    }
}

struct Eta<T: Alpha, U: StringRawRepresentable where T.Beta == U> {
    let alpha: T
    let beta: U
    init(alpha: T, beta: U) {
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.beta = beta
        println("beta is: \(beta.toRaw())")
    }
}

let gamma = Gamma()
Eta(alpha: gamma, beta: .Delta) // "beta is delta"
```

Is there a way that I can declare the `typealias` differently in the **original example** to restrict `RawRepresentable` to `String`?

---

## Update

Specifying `U: RawRepresentable where U.Raw == String` seemed hopeful, so I gave that a try:

```
protocol Alpha {
    typealias Beta: RawRepresentable
}

struct Gamma: Alpha {
    enum Beta: String {
        case Delta = "delta"
    }
}

struct Eta<T: Alpha, U: RawRepresentable where T.Beta == U, U.Raw == String> {
    let alpha: T
    let beta: U
    init(alpha: T, beta: U) {
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.beta = beta

        // Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT).
        println("beta is: \(beta.toRaw())")
    }
}

let gamma = Gamma()
Eta(alpha: gamma, beta: .Delta) // "beta is delta"

struct Epsilon: Alpha {
    enum Beta: Int {
        case Zeta = 6
    }
}

let epsilon = Epsilon()
Eta(alpha: epsilon, beta: .Zeta) // Error only occurs when this is executed
```

While this technically prevents using anything other than a `String`, I'm looking for a compile-time constraint and this appears to be causing a runtime exception.

I'd also prefer that this be enforced by the protocol if possible rather than consumers needing to check that `.Raw == String`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031646/how-in-swift-specify-type-constraint-to-be-enum ?

Comment: I did, and answers there describe what I've shown in my examples.

Answer (score 8):

Just to add onto this since it's a bit older, your updated example works in swift 2+ now and will complain at compile time that .Zeta is ambiguous unless it's a String type.

You can also put the check in a pattern match for a protocol extension. As an example:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element:RawRepresentable,
                         Generator.Element.RawValue == String {
    func toStringArray() -> [String] {
        return self.map { $0.rawValue }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side-note, I believe this is how Apple handles `CodingKey`

Answer (score 3):

This should now be possible. For example, the following protocol allows a class to define its own enumeration of 'input' parameters conforming to string:

```
protocol AttributeContainer {
   associatedtype InputKey: RawRepresentable where InputKey.RawValue: StringProtocol
   func set(value: Any?, for inputKey: InputKey)
}
```

This could be used as follows:

```
class MyClass: AttributeContainer {

    enum AttributeKey: String {
       case attributeA, attributeB, attributeC
    }

    func set(value: Any?, for inputKey: InputKey) {
        // Handle the setting of attributes here
    }

}
```

This is similar to how Apple handles `CodingKey` in the `Codable` protocol. I find it useful when doing things like storing arbitrary class types in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at our options here. First, it's (as of Xcode 6 beta 5) a well known restriction that we cannot specify enum type constraints in the easy and expected way. Second, you need something very clear: to be able to call `fromRaw(String)`. And third, you want a compiler error. I'd say your best bet is to write a protocol to do exactly that, and push down to the consumer the requirement to ensure s/he gives you a `fromRaw(String)`. In this case, here's what I would do, simplifying your second code snippet:

```
protocol Alpha {
    typealias Beta: RawRepresentable
    func fromRaw(raw: String) -> Beta?
}

struct Gamma: Alpha {
    enum Beta: String {
        case Delta = "delta"
        case Omega = "omega"
    }
    func fromRaw(raw: String) -> Beta? {
        return Beta.fromRaw(raw)
    }
}

struct Eta<T: Alpha, U: RawRepresentable where T.Beta == U> {
    let alpha: T
    let beta: U
    init(alpha: T, beta: U) {
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.beta = beta
        println("beta is: \(beta.toRaw())")
    }
}

let gamma = Gamma()
let a = Eta(alpha: gamma, beta: .Delta) // "beta is delta"
println(gamma.fromRaw("delta"))  // Optional(Enum Value)
println(gamma.fromRaw("omega")!) // Enum Value
```

Philosophically this is imho more aligned with your needs: You say "I want something not only RawRepresentable, but also a `fromRaw(String)`. Figure out how you give it to me".
The Gamma struct is the simplest example, where the consumer specifics his enum, and then says "ok, I can give you my standard `fromRaw()` because it works.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague and I talked this out and in Swift 2.0/2.1, you can do this with a protocol: https://gist.github.com/designatednerd/5645d286df0ce939714b

Tried it out in an app I'm working with, works like a charm. :)

Comment: This isn't as useful because while the enums aren't RawRepresentable, you can't do `Wat(rawValue: "Steve")`