# Is it possible to declare swift generic for enums of particular type?

Tags: swift

Would it be possible to have a function that allows any enum where the rawValue is of a certain type? For example, any enum that has a string rawValue.

Answer (score 16):

This can be done using generics and the "where" keyword

```
enum EnumString: String {
    case A = "test"
}

func printEnum<T: RawRepresentable where T.RawValue == String>(arg: T) {
    print(arg.rawValue)
}
printEnum(EnumString.A) //Prints "test"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a generic that conforms to the type `RawRepresentable`, which is a protocol that all enums declaring a primitive rawValue conform to.

```
enum EnumA: Int {
    case A = 0
}

enum EnumB {
    case A
}

func doGenericSomething<T: RawRepresentable>(arg: T) {
    println(arg.rawValue)
}

doGenericSomething(EnumA.A) //OK
doGenericSomething(EnumB.A) //Error! Does not conform to protocol RawRepresentable
```

You cannot, however, specify an enum's rawValue type in a generic. For information you can see the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031646/how-in-swift-specify-type-constraint-to-be-enum).