# In Swift, how can you use generic enum types in protocol extensions?

Tags: swift, enums

I want to share functionality between `CatZoo` and `DogZoo` since they're storing similar data under the hood but I also want them to know what they are so they can act on their specific data, as shown in the `DogZoo.makeNoise()` method.

What is the correct type for `AnimalStorageProtocol.storage`?

```
enum CatType: String {
    case lion
    case tiger
    case panther
}

enum DogType: String {
    case coyote
    case domestic
    case wolf
}

struct CatZoo: AnimalStorageProtocol {
    private var storage: [CatType: Int] // it's a bonus if they can stay private
}

struct DogZoo: AnimalStorageProtocol {
    private var storage: [DogType: Int]

    func makeNoise() {
        for (key, value) in storage {
            switch key  {
            case .coyote:
                print("\(value) yips!")
            case .domestic:
                print("\(value) barks!")
            case .wolf:
                print("\(value) howls!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought I could define a generic enum type [in the protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415043/is-it-possible-to-declare-swift-generic-for-enums-of-particular-type) but I haven't been able to get it to work.

```
protocol AnimalStorageProtocol {
    // var storage: <RawRepresentable where RawRepresentable.RawValue == String: Int> { get set }
    var storage: [RawRepresentable: Int] { get set }
}

extension AnimalStorageProtocol {
    var isEmpty: Bool {
        get {
            for (_, value) in storage {
                if value != 0 {
                    return false
                }
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different way you could do it depending on what your requirements are.

---

If you don't require the type to be a enum, you can simply do

```
protocol AnimalStorageProtocol {
    associatedtype AnimalType: Hashable
    var storage: [AnimalType: Int] { get set }
}
```

This will allow any hashable type to be used.

---

If you require that the types can only be `RawRepresentable` where the `RawValue` is a `String` you'll have to define another protocol that your animal types will have to conform to.

```
protocol AnimalType: Hashable, RawRepresentable {
    var rawValue: String { get }
}

protocol AnimalStorageProtocol {
    associatedtype Animal: AnimalType
    var storage: [Animal: Int] { get set }
}
```

Then you just have to set your enum types to conform to the `AnimalType` protocol.

```
enum CatType: String, AnimalType { ... }
enum DogType: String, AnimalType { ... }
```

Comment: Great answer. I went with the second approach. Works great with protocol extensions like these: `var isEmpty: Bool { get { return storage.filter { $0.value != 0 }.count == 0 } }` and `static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool { return lhs.storage == rhs.storage }`