# Test if instance is a protocol with typealias in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765806/can-my-class-override-protocol-property-type-in-swift).  Using typealias I can create a class that has a "children" var but with a specific type, which is what I'm looking for.  But when I do that I can no longer test to see if an instance follows that protocol.  I have also tried 'if let' and that doesn't work.  Is there any way to do this?

```
protocol Parent {
    typealias Child
    var children: [Child] { get set }
}

protocol Child {
    typealias Parent
    var parent: Parent { get set }

}

class Foo: Parent {
    var children = [Bar]()

    init(){}
}

class Bar: Child {
    var parent = Foo()
}

let testVar = Foo()
let cVar = Bar()

testVar.children.append(cVar)
cVar.parent = testVar

//I get the error here saying protocol is limited to generic constraints
if testVar is Parent { 

}
```

Comment: I actually don't think that this would make much sense (The compiler has its reasons) or be used for something. Can you maybe expand your question with your intention?

Comment: @Kametrixom I have about 5 different classes that have the same variable "children" and some have the same variable "parent".  These all have things in common but sometimes instead of type checking each one I prefer to type check if it's a parent class which means it is guaranteed to have a "children" variable that I want to access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to solve this statically (at least for now). So a more dynamic approach would be to have a "super" protocol which has no self associated type requirements. This allows you to cast between these "super" protocols:

```
protocol _Parent {
    var anyChildren: [Any] { get set }
}
protocol Parent: _Parent {
    typealias Child
    var children: [Child] { get set }
}

extension Parent {
    // requirement of _Parent
    var anyChildren: [Any] {
        get {
            return children.map{ $0 as Any }
        }
        set {
            // use `as!` and `map` if you are sure that all elements are of type Child
            // or if you want a crash if not
            children = newValue.flatMap{ $0 as? Child }
        }
    }
}

protocol _Child {
    var anyParent: Any { get set }
}

protocol Child: _Child {
    typealias Parent
    var parent: Parent { get set }
}

extension Child {
    // requirement of _Child
    var anyParent: Any {
        get {
            return parent
        }
        set {
            parent = newValue as! Parent
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use their properties to manipulate the data:

```
class Foo: Parent {
    var children = [Foo]()
}

let anything: Any = Foo()

// use `if let` and `as?` instead of `is` in order to have a more static type
if let aDynamicParent = anything as? _Parent {
    aDynamicParent.anyChildren.map{ $0 as! Foo } // cast the array back to its original type

    aDynamicParent.children = [Foo(), Foo(), Foo()]
}
```

Comment: Never thought about doing it this way but that'll work. I suppose it is a workaround for now but still, hopefully next version of Swift will implement something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Child` and `Parent` typealiases if `Parent` contains array of objects conforming `Child` protocol and `Child` contains `Parent` protocol property.

```
protocol Parent {
    var children: [Child] { get set }
}

protocol Child {
    var parent: Parent { get nonmutating set }
}

class Foo: Parent {
    var children: [Child]
    init(children: [Child]) {
        self.children = children
        self.children.forEach { $0.parent = self }
    }
}

class Bar: Child {
    var parent: Parent
    init(parent: Parent) {
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.children.append(self)
    }
}

let testVar = Foo(children: [Bar]())
let cVar = Bar(parent: testVar)

let parent = testVar as Parent 
let children = parent.children
```

Comment: But what if I want Foo's children to be only of type Bar?